# Can my .NET application auto encrypt it self or part of it?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I've an application "A". 
I've a Second application called "B" that is used to run "A"

to run "A" you first run "B", input a password then, "B" decrypts "A", then "A" is executed!

now the problem is, when i close "A" i want it back encrypted! right now the only way is to run again "B" encrypt and then quit B.

I can run "B" at the when i close "A" as OnClose routing, and ecncrypt "A" again.

BUT!

What if instead of closing "A" for some reason it crashes? I need a way to be sure then when i terminate process "A" it automatically get auto encrypted again.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you think encrypting is a solution?

Comment: I bet that the encryption key is stored as clear text in "A"

Comment: More likely the key would be stored in 'B', and even if it isn't I'm sure it's IL will tell you how to find it.

Comment: @M.Babcock: hehe. All A:s and B:s made by head start to spin ;)

Comment: You are describing a security problem without saying *who the attacker is* or *what the threat they pose is*. It sounds like you are saying that the attacker is *the user* and the threat they pose is to *you*, the software provider. That is completely backwards; trust flows *from the user*, not *from the software developer*. The .NET security system is designed to protect *users* from *hostile software developers*, not protect software developers from *hostile users*.  If your users cannot be trusted to see your software **do not sell it to them in the first place**.

Comment: I've added a comment below but let me recap.  There is no hardcoded key anywhere. The B application encrypts the A application with AES 256 the key is given in input at start up from a method that is not relevant to this topic.

Comment: @EricLippert This is not a program for sale. The software is never executed by other users but users will have the encrypted version of the software ( yes without the possibility of using it ). The problem is still in place, i need on close or on SIGTERM or crash a way to automatically re-encrypt the .exe program. Does anyone has some suggestion apart from putting "execute B" inside the OnClose() routine?

Comment: @NoobTom: Whether it is for sale or not is irrelevant; if the user can *run* your software on *their machine* then *you are working for them*, not vice versa. Look at it from the perspective of the user. *How do they know that your encrypted program is safe for them to run*?

Comment: I am the one running the program, i wrote it...i am not going to infect myself for how bad programmer i can be :D

Comment: So you are encrypting the program to stop *yourself* from reading the encrypted program?  Again: **you are asking security questions without first describing the threat or the attacker**. No one can give you a sensible answer to a question about building defenses without knowing what the attack is.

Answer (score 1):

As others have hinted, you are more likely to cause problems then solve anything. The code in "B" can be inspected using free software (ILSpy, for example) - it would take a hostile developer less than half an hour to create their own version of "B" without the password.

Aside from that: you should not decrypt "A" on disk - even a beginner user could just copy paste the result before shutting down "A". To counter that, "B" would have to decrypt "A" and run "A" from memory in a separate AppDomain.

Comment: Thank for your replay. No you people are wrong let me illustrate why. The principle of open design illustrates that the security of a scheme does not depend on the added complexity and on the secrecy of its design. Now, my B encryption program when executed, asks for a key that will be given in input. The key is generated using PBKDF2.  There is no hardcoded key anyway. The reason why i need to encrypt the program A is because i need the propertiy of confidentiality to be in place. A must be confidential and in this scenario this mean encrypted with AES256

Comment: It seemed obvious that the program is never execute by a user that can copy paste it. My only threat is that once the process A close/dies for some reason is not re-encrypted.